# Output dynamic array without duplicate elements (shrink the array) C++

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic

I need to generate **dynamic** array and remove duplicate elements (shrink the array) (1,2,2,3 ==== 1,2,3) using loops and elementary code. I created an array but don't know how to delete elements. Maybe, by copying unique elements to new array.

```
void RandArrayA(int * A, const int m)
{
    srand(time(0));

    for (int a = 0; a < m; a++)
    {
        A[a] = rand() % 10 * (1 - 2 * (rand() % 2));
        cout << A[a] << " ";
    }

    cout << endl;
}

void Find(int * A, const int m)
{

}
```

Comment: Hint: You can't delete elements from an array, you can only overwrite them

Comment: I need to shrink the array

Comment: Must you preserve the order? I mean, if you're given `1 3 2 3 4 5`, what must you return?

Comment: 1 3 2 4 5 remove the second duplicate

Comment: Does the result need to keep the same order as the input? Do non-consecutive duplicate elements get removed? Which ones?

Comment: the same order as input, just remove founded duplicate
1,3,5,4,5 ==== 1,3,5,4

Comment: Unrelated: The positioning of `srand(time(0));` is questionable. `srand` seeds and restarts the generator, something you rarely want to do more than once a program (and if you do, odds are good that `rand` and `srand` are not sufficient for your random number generating needs). Because `time` has the fairly course grain of one second, if you call `RandArrayA` multiple times in a short period of time, you'll find yourself generating large numbers of duplicate arrays. Typical usage is to call `srand(time(0));` once near the beginning of the `main` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't delete elements. The array has a fixed size.

However, you can fake it, by getting them out of the way and pretending they don't exist any more.

When you detect a "duplicate", move it to the end of the array. (You may need to shuffle all the subsequent elements along to make room for it, or you can use some fancy swapping shenanigans if you don't care too much about order).

Then, if you have detected *x* duplicates in total, out of a total of *n* values, then you need only print the first *n-x* values of the array. This "hides" the duplicates.

They're still there, at the end of the array, but you don't need to do anything with them.

Let's look at your dataset:

```
Original:    1,3,5,4,5   (5 elements)
Reorganised: 1,3,5,4,5   (1 duplicate; therefore, 4 useful elements)
```

Unfortunately this is not a good demonstrating example, because the only duplicate value was *already* at the end of the dataset!

Picking a random alternative dataset:

```
Original:    1,1,3,4,5,6,5,8   (8 elements)
Reorganised: 1,3,4,5,6,8,1,5   (2 duplicates; therefore, 6 useful elements)
```

---

*As an aside, this "moving to the end" is how `std::remove` and friends work, and why you then need to do a `std::erase` to finally obliterate the container elements holding the "hidden" values.*

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I forgot to write that we can create second array and copy there unique elements from the first but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: @Alina: In my second example, you can create an array of size 6 and copy the 6 useful elements into it? Honestly though it's pointless to do that.

Comment: OK. Thank you. :-) I am new to C++

Comment: @Alina Good luck!